# Different way how add image to resources

Tags: wpf, image, resources

Hi I found 2 two ways how add image to resources.

First is: For example I create folder images and add some images to this folder, set images build action on Resources. Something like here:

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/07/23/bind-an-image-to-a-property-in-wpf/

And second way is use Resources.resx and use AddResources -> AddExistingFile.

Is the result same?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not the same.

WPF resources should use the "Resource" build action. Resx resources (aka "Embedded resource") are used by Windows Forms, not WPF. They resolve to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, but WPF needs a `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`, so you can't use Resx images directly in WPF (you can however convert from a `Bitmap` to an `ImageSource`, using the `System.Windows.Interop.Imaging` class)

Comment: Thank you for explaining, now I understand the difference.