# XamlParseException on setting image from resources

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, resources, ribbon

i got some trouble. I just implemented the Microsoft Ribbon Framework into my application. Now i wanted to set an icon for one button. So i wrote:

```
    <Ribbon:RibbonButton Header="Create Project" LargeImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/document_empty.png" />
```

But everytime i start the app, i got an "XamlParseException" in this line, with the inner exception: "File not found".

Why the hell is this so? I don´t understand, why it doesn´t find the image. It´s just placed in the resources of the assembly. The designer show´s it and the code doesn´t get highlighted as it was an syntax error or something like that...

Anyone who has this problem too?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you simply set `LargeImageSource="Resources/document_empty.png"`? The `pack://application:` stuff should be done automatically.

Comment: Same problem. I tried "/Resources/document_empty.png" and "/Resources\document_empty.png" nothing worked ...

Comment: Hmm, and the Build Action for `document_empty.png` is `Resource`?

Comment: And the image is on the root level, ie. not in a sub folder??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you haven't specified exactly, I assume you are using the Properties\resources.resx part of your application? If so this is not the desired way for a WPF application.

See this [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775030/different-way-how-add-image-to-resources)

Instead create a folder in your assembly, place your images in there and set its build action to resource.

See picture:
[image]

In your Markup use the packUri:

> pack://application:,,,/images/IMG.jpg

Comment: Ah, good to know. Yes i´m using the .resx part.
But even if i change the images automatically created in an "Resource" folder in the assembly to "Resource" Compile-action, i get the same result ...

Comment: Added an image which should make it clearer; don't use the resx part of your application. Tip: If you have more than a few images I'd consider making a separate assembly where the images reside and reference them from your other assemblies ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i will definitely do this.
But by the way... it still doesn´t work.

I always get this ParseException. That´s my URI:
"<Ribbon:RibbonButton Label="Create Project" LargeImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Icons/document_empty.png" />"

And another question: How do i link to the other assembly using a URI?

Comment: Ok i found it out: "pack://application:,,,/MyApp.Resources;component/Icons/Large/document_empty.png" :) But same problem ...

Comment: Sry I don't have a clue why it doesn't work; Have you tried narrowing down the problem, like using another image file, using another control (instead of ribbon button)? Is the document_empty.png valid?

Comment: Ah ... a long time later i found the problem.
I just found out, that Visual Studio can´t handle chain-references. So the assembly never landed in the bin of the "start"-project. And so the exception came. Now it works, but i have to find a solution to copy the references for the future -.-

So thanks for the help :)